# Examples of Heyting categories that are not toposes?

Tags: topos-theory, categorical-logic

When explaining how Heyting categories can model first order logic it would be nice to be able to give some small example and contrast it with Set-semantics. I realized however that I don't know of any Heyting category which is not also a topos. It would be nice to have more concrete examples to give.

A search netted me a [master thesis](https://scholarworks.umt.edu/etd/1124/) that discussed the Heyting category structure on some categories of graphs. Do you have other examples of Heyting categories that are not toposes?

EDIT: Syntactic categories are Heyting categories which are not necessarily toposes as pointed out by godelian. I am however looking for examples not arising out of logic (:

Comment: Any first-order (intuitionistic) theory gives rise to a small Heyting category: its syntactic category. See e.g. Johnstone

Comment: Yes, that's true, I had something more concrete in mind though, that I could show someone who is less familiar with categorical logic.

Comment: In the category of sets, take the full subcategory whose objects are the countable sets. This looks to me like a Heyting category, also satisfying classical logic.

Comment: A similar sort of example is the category of classes (relative to some model of set theory).